# Python: Multi-line comments using AutoHotkey

Tags: python, comments, autohotkey

First, I'm just learning Python 3.6 and am coding my first program.

After much Googling regarding multi-line comments in Python, I found 3 answers:

- 1. Use a # to start a comment which extends to the end of the line only. --- This is 100% official commenting.
- 2. Use triple " characters as in (""") before and after the multi-line comments. --- But this will not work if used in doc strings.
- 3. Some IDE's can comment out multiple lines. --- But I'm assuming that the comments may not be commented out if the code is edited in a different IDE edit program, and definitely not commented out if edited in Notepad.

So to be 100% officially correct with no gotchas, I want to use AutoHotkey to write the '#' character at the beginning of every line of my multi-line comments.  My plan is:

..... Use (alt + .) to do a "Home, write #space, down arrow"

..... Use (alt + /) to do a "Home, delete 2 characters, down arrow"

This should allow me to comment or uncomment one or multiple lines very rapidly.  All comments will be 100% official Python comments. Note that there will be a space after each # character so deletion requires 2 char delete.

My question is this:  Is the (alt + .) or (alt + /) key combos used in Python programming at all?  If so, any other key combo suggestions?

Comment: I use "alt + /" all the time...

Comment: Consider using a proper python IDE like PyCharm that correctly comments/uncomments multiple lines using `#` at the start when you press Ctrl /

Comment: >> Consider using a proper python IDE like PyCharm that correctly comments/uncomments multiple lines using # at the start when you press Ctrl / – wOxxOm << --- I tried that in PyCharm and it works like a charm.  No need to use AutoHotkey.  Thanks  for your response :)

Comment: >> I use "alt + /" all the time... – Huy Vo << --- Thanks for taking the time to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Though this was answered in comments by advising the use of an IDE, the typical functionality of said IDE's for commenting a single line is adding a "#" and space at the beginning of said line.

The below code accomplishes this for those preferring AHK:

```
^/::
{
Sendinput {Home}{#}{Space}
}
return
```